# three.js 3d modal blurred

Tags: three.js, 3d, blender

I bought a tshirt 3d model in the format .fbx. I'm using this tutorial to get started with three.js: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/09/17/how-to-build-a-color-customizer-app-for-a-3d-model-with-three-js/

I exported the .fbx model in blender to a .glb file. This .glb file is used in my three.js website. On the website parts of the tshirt are blurred, some parts look like they should. Here is a comparison image with the blender model (dark) and the blurred three.js model (light): https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSeDj.jpg

What can I do? Do I have to change something in blender prior to the export or do I have to change the three.js code from the tutorial?

Comment: Can you please try out to turn of shadows by setting `receiveShadow` and `castShadow` to `false`? Does it look more like you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mugen87 stated, the solution was to set `receiveShadow` and `castShadow` to `false`.